# An integral I got on my midterm exam

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Derive a recursive formula for the integral $I(n) = \int_0^1x^{m}\ln^{n}(x)\,dx$
and then solve the integral for $m = 0$.

I have tried using partial integration as follows:

$$
u = \ln^{n}(x) \implies \,du = \frac{n\cdot \ln^{n-1}(x)}{x}\,dx \\dv=x^{m}\,dx \implies v = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}
$$

So now I have

$$
I(n) = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\ln^{n}(x)|_0^1 - \frac{n}{m+1}\underbrace{\int_0^1x^{m}\ln^{n-1}(x)\,dx}_{I(n-1)}
$$

The problem is that $\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\ln^{n}(x)|_0^1$ is not defined for $x = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: find the limit of 
$\frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}\ln^{n}(x)$ at zero.

Comment: And now I'm pissed off I didn't solve it during the exam. I've even tried finding the limit, it turned out to be $0$, and then I made some mistakes while checking the solution, so I discarded it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the integral itself is not well-defined at $x=0$. You need to view it as the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit of $I(n) = \int_\epsilon^1x^{m}\ln^{n}(x)\,dx$.

Now use the fact that for $m>0$, $$\lim_{x \to 0} x^m \ln^n (x) = 0$$ and it will work. You can prove this, for example, using a substitution.